# Invoke Issue, failed to convert parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

Okay in unity I'm trying to use Invoke to call a method given in a string format. I can get it to work with no parameters but using parameters it fails, and I can't figure it.

```
public string SetCVar(string args)
{
    return "hello";
}


public string ParseCmdString(string str)
{
    // Find Cmd string
    string cmdStr = str.Split(' ')[0];

    if(cCmds.ContainsKey(cmdStr.ToLower()))
    {
        Cmd cmd = cCmds[cmdStr];

        System.Type         objType = cmd.obj.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = objType.GetMethod(cmd.method, new System.Type[]{typeof(string)});

        return (string)method.Invoke(objType, new object[]{str});
    }


    return "Command not found!";
}
```

if `SetCVar` has no parameters its fine other wise I get the following error.

```
ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Invoke` call should invoke on the instance, not the type:

```
return (string)method.Invoke(cmd.obj, new object[]{str});
```

Comment: argh, sorry my tired eyes - typo in question it should be str not cmd, which is a string, I'll edit question.

Comment: @PhilCK Okay - just edited to show the next issue I see now ;)